# Capture all segments of path in Akka/Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to capture each segment of the URL path in AkkaHTTP with Java.

Here's my code:

```
public Route routes() {
    return route(pathPrefix("users", () ->
        route(
            getOrPostUsers(),
            path(PathMatchers.segment(), name -> route(
                getUser(name),
                deleteUser(name),
                path(PathMatchers.segment(), countryOfResidence -> route(
                  getUser(name, countryOfResidence),
                  deleteUser(name, countryOfResidence)
                ))
              )
            )

        )
    ));
}
```

So, as you can see, I'm trying to grab the first segment of the URL path and store it as `name` and the second segment of the URL path and store it as `countryOfResidence`.  An example URL for this would be something like

`localhost:8080/users/ian/usa`

If a user enters only `localhost:8080/users/ian`, I want to route to the version of the function getUser() or deleteUser(), depending on the type of HTTP request, that accepts only a name.  If the user inputs a longer URL, as stated above, I'd like to to call the versions of getUser() or deleteUser() that take two parameters.

Whenever I run the above code, the PathMatcher for name works perfectly fine.  The issue arises when I run the PathMatcher for name and countryOfResidence.  The code in those routes never runs, and the server doesn't return any JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the directives are attempted in order, so the shorter ones will match before the more specific ones are tried. I suggest you try to either:

- put the most specific path first (`path(PathMatchers.segment(), countryOfResidence ...`), so that it can match before the shorter ones match or
- suffix the shorter cases with a directive to match pathEndOrSingleSlash(), so that they explicitly won't match the longer paths:

  ```
      path(PathMatchers.segment(), name -> route(
          pathEndOrSingleSlash(() -> route(
            getUser(name),
            deleteUser(name)
          ),
          path(PathMatchers.segment(), countryOfResidence -> route(
            getUser(name, countryOfResidence),
            deleteUser(name, countryOfResidence)
          ))
        )
      )
  ```